# Какие хорошие практики сохранения информации между страницами существуют в android?

Tags: android

Пользователь заходит на форму и заполняет что то, есть информация которая может пригодиться если пользователь захочет перейти на другую страницу(продублировать). На сущность эта информация не тянет, поэтому в БД нет особого желания сохранять.
В android я полный 0, хочу понять в каком направлении лучше идти.
Возможно тут подходит Context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вводите через форму `EditText`, то тогда можно передать через `Intent PutExtra` на следующую активность, там принимать и обрабатывать. Если вводимую информацию нужно вернуть, то тогда `startActivityForResult` будет ждать результата, и в метод можно положить значения , которые мы ждем. Если нужно сохранять информацию то тут можно базу данных. `Realm` или `Sqlite` как вариант. Для простых случаев можно заюзать `SharedPreferences`

> Возможно тут подходит Context?

Context тут не причем